# Expectation = Probability?

Tags: probability, integration, limits, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

The paper ["The Distribution of the Maxima of a Random Curve"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2371510?read-now=1&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) derives a certain probability as the following integral (p. 413):
$$\int_{y_0}^{y_0+\Delta y}d\xi\int_{0}^{M_2\Delta x}d\eta\int_{-M_2}^{\eta/\Delta x}d\zeta\ P(\xi,\eta,\zeta)\tag{a}
$$
and says ...

> Therefore this integral cannot differ from $q(\Delta x, \Delta y)$ by more than terms of order $\Delta y(\Delta x)^2.$ By changing the order of integration, using the mean value theorem for integrals and the fact that $P(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$ is a continuous function of all its variables, it may be shown that $$\lim_{\Delta x, \Delta y\to 0} {q(\Delta x, \Delta y)\over \Delta x\Delta y}=-\int_{-M_2}^0 P(y_0,0,\zeta)\,\zeta\,d\zeta\tag{b}$$

Obtaining the RHS of (b) from (a) is apparently supposed to be straightforward, but would someone kindly explain this in more detail?

Comment: Perhaps more context is required. Also, the paper is behind a paywall.

Comment: I've totally rewritten your question by focusing on the point in the paper where the "expectation-like" integral arises. It's now a purely mathematical question of how to take the limit of a certain multiple integral. Please re-edit if I have not captured the essence of your question.

Comment: Note that $P(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$ denotes the joint probability density function of the random vector $(F,{\partial F\over \partial x},{\partial^2 F\over \partial x^2})$. The same result is also briefly derived in the paper ["The Statistical Distribution of the Maxima of a Random Function"](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rspa.1956.0173) by D. E. Cartwright and M. S. Longuet-Higgins (p. 213-214).

Comment: "Obtaining the RHS of (b) from (a) ", I just want to know where the $\zeta$ in b comes from?

Comment: @r.e.s.  Maybe my problem is too trivial. Like  "The statistical Distribution of the Maxima of a Random Function" (p237)  (1.5),  if you want get a probability ,you integral the probability density funciton. If you want get an expectation, you integrate the pdf  times the  variable.But both (b) and (1.5) is probability ,and integrate form like a expectation.Sorry for my bad English .

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because no one else has replied, I'll post an answer (although it's been many years since I've dealt with limits of multiple integrals) ...

For convenience, I'm going to write $u,v,w$ in place of $\xi,\eta,\zeta,$ so the quantity of interest is
$$\begin{align}&\lim_{\Delta x, \Delta y\to 0} {q(\Delta x, \Delta y)\over \Delta x\Delta y}\\
&= \lim_{\Delta x, \Delta y\to 0} {1\over \Delta x\Delta y}\int_{y_0}^{y_0+\Delta y}du\int_{0}^{M_2\Delta x}dv\int_{-M_2}^{v/\Delta x}dw\ P(u,v,w)\tag{1}\\[2ex]
&=\lim_{\Delta x, \Delta y\to 0} {1\over \Delta x\Delta y}\int_{y_0}^{y_0+\Delta y}du\int_{-M_2}^{0}dw\int_{0}^{-w\,\Delta x}dv\ P(u,v,w)\tag{2}\\[2ex]
&=\lim_{\Delta x, \Delta y\to 0} {1\over \Delta x\Delta y}\int_{y_0}^{y_0+\Delta y}du\int_{-M_2}^{0}dw\ P(u,c_{\Delta x},w)\,(-w\Delta x)\tag{3}\\[2ex]
&=\lim_{\Delta x, \Delta y\to 0} {1\over \Delta x\Delta y}\int_{-M_2}^{0}dw\ P(c_{\Delta y},c_{\Delta x},w)\,(\Delta y)\,(-w\Delta x)\tag{4}\\[2ex]
&=\lim_{\Delta x, \Delta y\to 0} \int_{-M_2}^{0}dw\ P(c_{\Delta y},c_{\Delta x},w)\,(-w)\tag{5}\\[2ex]
&=-\int_{-M_2}^{0}dw\ P(y_0,0,w)\,w\tag{6}\\[2ex]
\end{align}$$

where

- $(1)\implies(2)$ by changing the order of integration on $(v,w)$, noting that the region of integration in the $(v,w)$-plane is a triangle bounded by $0<v<M_2\Delta x$ on the $v$-axis,$-M_2<w<0$ on the $w$-axis, and the line $w=-v/\Delta x,$ i.e., the line $v=-w\Delta x$.
- $(2)\implies(3)$ by the mean value theorem for integrals, $(-w\Delta x)$ being the width of the interval of integration on $v$, i.e. $[0,-w\Delta x]$, and $c_{\Delta x}$ being some value in that interval.
- $(3)\implies(4)$, again by the mean value theorem, where $c_{\Delta y}\in[y_0,y_0+\Delta y].$
- $(4)\implies(5)$, dividing through by $\Delta x\,\Delta y$.
- $(5)\implies(6)$, because $c_{\Delta y}$ and $c_{\Delta x}$ are confined to intervals that converge to the points $\{y_0\}$ and $\{0\}$, respectively.

**NB**: This result is *not* obtained by considering it to be some sort of expectation value, even though the integrand is a product of $w$ and the joint probability density function evaluated at $(u,v)=(y_0,0).$ (An expectation requires the product to be $w$ and the *marginal probability density* for $w$, which is not obtained from the joint density by simply plugging in constants for $(u,v)$. Maybe it can be seen as the limit of some such?)

Comment: Just no words can express my excitement and gratitude!

Comment: What do you think of the $\zeta$ come from in my origin problem which in the paper page 410 formula (3).

Comment: @Codemx  p.410 begins with (a fragment of) the sentence "The discussion given in the section entitled 'Theory' establishes the following result ... [p.410 (3) follows]". So, the $\zeta$ you're asking about comes from that 'Theory' section, and the steps I posted above refer to the exact place in that section where that occurrence of $\zeta$ arises -- in particular, it's at my step $(2)\implies(3)$. (Note that my equation (6) is exactly the author's p.410 (3), because he defines $p(x_0,y_0)$ to be the limit we're discussing.)

Comment: Now I fully understand.Thanks for your generous explianation,